# Find the index of 2nd occurence of an element in an Integer ArrayList using streams in java

Tags: java, arraylist

for example i have an ArrayList containing elements:-
ArrayList a = {1,0,0,1,0,1};

I want to find here the index of the 2nd occurence of integer 1 which is at 3rd index in Arraylist a using streams.

Comment: Any reason for not just using a basic loop?

Comment: i just want a code as short as possible to use this solution to solve a bigger sub-problem

Comment: You mean `IntStream.range(0, a.size()).filter(i -> a.get(i) == 1).skip(1).findFirst()`? But a loop may be more readable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no research or own implementation efforts.

Comment: Do you mean find the _index_ of the second occurrence? Or just if there is a second occurrence? Or the value of the second occurrence if there is one (spoiler, it’s `1`)?

Comment: index of the second occurence

Comment: I don't think there's any good way to do this using existing APIs as a one-liner. Just make a loop and extract it to a separate method. Although I did come up with this cursed mess, just for fun >:) `list.subList(list.indexOf(1) + 1, list.size()).indexOf(1) + list.indexOf(1) + 1`

Comment: Something like `public static <T> int nthIndexOf(List<T> list, T search, int nth) `

Comment: @Rubydesic thank you very much its working ... i tried here is my approach

Comment: Integer z=a.subList(a.indexOf(1) + 1, a.size()).indexOf(1) + a.indexOf(1) + 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find the index of 2nd occurence of an element in an Integer ArrayList using **streams** in java

You could do it like this. If the item or itemNo is not found, it returns -1 via an Optional.

- create a Map<Integer,List>
- the key is the list element, the value is a list of indices at which it occurs.
- then just get the list for the element `item` and the specify `itemNo` as the ordinal value (2nd in this case) to get.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1);
int item = 1; // for item 1
int itemNo = 2; // get the second value
Optional<Integer> index = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list::get))
        .getOrDefault(item, List.of(0))
        .stream().skip(itemNo-1).findFirst();
        
System.out.println(index.orElseGet(()->-1));
```

prints

```
3
```

Of course, in practice, one would just use a loop.